# ecception to this .htaccess rule specific pdf link are allowed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added this `.htaccess` rule to a WordPress website

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in_([a-zA-Z0-9_]*) [NC]
   RewriteRule \.(zip|doc|docx|pdf)$ – [NC,F,L]
</IfModule>
```

This rule work right but I want to give an exception.

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/name-of-pdf.pdf
```

must be visible even if your not logged in.

Comment: Then replace the RewriteCond that currently performs an absolutely bogus check (of course the request filename will _always_ match `(.*)`- _anything_ does), with a negated one that explicitly does not allow this specific one.

Comment: That anyone setting themselves a cookie named `wordpress_logged_in_...` can easily circumvent this, is clear?

Comment: Easily for who?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} (.*)
> ```

Change this *condition* to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/name-of-pdf.pdf
```

The `!` prefix negates the expression, so it is successful when it does **not** match.

The `=` prefix operator makes this an exact string match, not a regex, so just use the complete URL-path as-is.

---

> must be visible even **if your not logged in**

Just to clarify (concern raised in comments)... this code does *not* check that the user is "logged in" (it does not authenticate the WP auth token). This simply checks for the existence of a cookie (ie. a `Cookie` HTTP request header that contains the value `wordpress_logged_in_`).

This might stop the casual user, but it is easily circumvented by the determined user so cannot be used to protect sensitive media.

Comment: A determined user that knows that server do this check in .htaccess file, how does he know it?